# Stop-start an elasticsearch instance having all the primary shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch (v5.6.10) cluster with 3 nodes.

- Node A : Master
- Node B : Master + Data
- Node C : Master + Data

There are 6 shards per data node with replication set as 1. All 6 primary nodes are in Node B and all 6 replicas are in Node C.

My requirement is to take out the Node B, do some maintenance work and put it back in cluster without any downtime.

I checked elastic documentation, discussion forum and stackoverflow questions. I found that I should execute the below request first in order to to allocate the shards on that node to the remaining nodes.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "transient" :{
      "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : <Node B IP>
   }
}';echo
```

Once all the shards have been reallocated I can shutdown the node and do my maintenance work. Once I am done, I have to include the node again for allocation and Elasticsearch will rebalance the shards again.

Now I also found another discussion where the user faced an issue of yellow/red cluster health issue due to having only one data node but wrongly setting replication as one, causing unassigned shards. It seems to me while doing this exercise I am taking my cluster towards that state.

So, my concern here is whether I am following the correct way keeping in mind all my primary shards are in the node (Node B) which I am taking out of a cluster having replication factor as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With only two data nodes and you wanting to shut down one, you can't really reallocate the shards. Elasticsearch never allocates primary and replica shards on the same nodes; it wouldn't add any benefit in availability or performance and would only double the disk space. So your reallocation command wouldn't add any benefit here since the shards cannot be moved anywhere.
2. Do a [synced flush](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-synced-flush-api.html) and then an [orderly shutdown of the node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/stopping-elasticsearch.html). The replica shards on the remaining node will automatically be promoted to primary shards. Your cluster will go yellow until the other node joins again, but there isn't really a way around it in your scenario (without being either a hack or an overkill). But this is fine — as long as you always have a replica it will be on the other node and your cluster will keep working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. One more question though. I came to know that a Kibana instance is running on Node B. As a result there is a primary shard for .kibana index in Node B and the corresponding replica in Node C. Once I take Node B out, all the replica shards in Node C will be promoted to primary including the .kibana one. Now when I join Node B again, it will hold the replica shards, so Kibana will now point to the replica copy of .kibana index instead of the primary one. Will it cause any issue ?

Comment: One more thing since there can't be any downtime to the elastic and it will keep on getting indexing request, is synced flush of any use here ?

Comment: Kibana or any other application doesn't need to care about primary or replica shard. Every request is handled by a so-called coordinating node (round robin between all your nodes) and that one will forward it to the right shard.

Comment: A sync flush should still help, since you will at least have a recent checkpoint to build on. Without any writes the recovery would be quicker; especially since your Elasticsearch version is so old that it doesn't have sequence IDs yet. But it will still work and not create any downtime; just the recovery will take longer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I don’t have any dedicated coordinating node in my Elasticsearch cluster, where Kibana is running, rather it is running in Node B (Master + Data). So won’t that cause any issue in my case.

Comment: Every node is implicitly a coordinating node — no problem if you don't have a dedicated one. The thing that you will have to fix / change though is where Kibana is pointing. We only added the ability to talk to multiple Elasticsearch nodes from Kibana in 6.6 or something like that, so you'll have to make sure you have Kibana running somewhere and pointing to node C (preferred) or A.

Comment: The suggestion of running kibana somewhere and pointing to Node C - Is this for the duration when Node B is out or this is a permanent change because even after Node B joins back it will hold the replica shard of .kibana index ?

Comment: Ideally you'd upgrade to a version where you can point to all / multiple Elasticsearch nodes for high availability. Otherwise I wouldn't care too much about primary and replica shard — assuming the network latency is low between the nodes. A read can go to either primary or replica shard and a write will go to both anyway.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I have another query. As I can't have any downtime to my cluster, I will constantly get indexing and search sequester while doing synced flush, taking Node B out, replica shards in Node C getting promoted to primary etc. Won't this affect anything specially the indexing requests ?

Comment: You can't gurantee that a couple of requests won't fail, but those should be handled by a retry (the Beats have that built in for example)